# Roots of ln of a square

Tags: logarithms, graphing-functions

### Problem:

$$
y=\ln((3x-2)^2)
$$

> State the domain and the coordinates of the point where the curve crosses the x-axis

At first sight, you say that the domain is $x>\frac23$ because $\ln$ is undefined for negative numbers, so you just rearrange $3x-2>0$.

But the input of $\ln$ is *squared*, which means there are 2 roots, namely $1$ and $\frac13$.

### Contradiction:

By the law of logarithms
$$
\ln(x^2)=2\ln(x)
$$
Therefore, the function for $y$ can be rewritten as
$$
y=2\ln(3x-2)
$$
The problem is that half the graph disappears. Now that the input isn't squared, $y$ is undefined for $x\le\frac23$ ($3x-2$ becomes negative) and the entire left half is gone.

---

So what's the answer? How many roots are there? It seems that math is contradicting itself.

Comment: Hint: for which values of $x$ do we have $(3x-2)^{2}>0$?

Comment: @WillR Well I _just_ read a post here about why the square root always returns the positive root, but _theoretically_ (and not really algebraically) both of the roots I suggested in my post would work.

Comment: There is a difference between the square root function (e.g. always returning a positive root) and reversing a squared operation from an expression (this gives a $\pm$ solution).

Comment: You will need to decide if the square is inside or outside of the logarithm function before you can solve the problem. Usually if it is inside that is written like $y = \ln((3x-2)^2)$ and outside $y = \ln(3x-2)^2$.

Comment: @mathreadler Edited to use more parentheses.

Comment: With $x<0$, $\ln(x^2)=2\ln(x)$ is obviously wrong.

Comment: Very handwavey but might help: All of these laws work once you know the domains are right, you can't figure out the domain from abusing the law.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your law of logarithms only works if the domain makes sense. You wouldn't write that $\ln((-4)^2)=2\ln(-4)$ as $\ln(-4)$ isn't defined. What would be better to write is actually:

$$\ln(x^2)=2\ln(|x|)$$

This would lead you to two solutions as:

$$\ln(3x-2)^2=0$$

$$2\ln(|3x-2|)=0$$

$$\ln(|3x-2|)=0$$

$$|3x-2|=1$$

$$3x-2=\pm1$$

$$3x=1,3$$

$$x=\frac{1}{3},1$$

Comment: I think you mean $\frac13$ and $1$, but the message comes across regardless. Thanks for a good explanation.

Comment: @Arc676 Yes. Fixed now. Oops.

Answer (score 7):

The error is in your simplicity, it should be
$$\ln x^2 = \ln |x|^2 = 2\ln |x|$$
As the square removes the negatives you cannot suddenly shoehorn them in and think it flies. Beyond that it's just a matter to solve for when $(3x-2)\neq 0$

Comment: +1 nice short explanation but :"shoehorn them in ... it flies" is rather a mixed metaphor.

Comment: yes, I shoehorned them in ;)